# Soft Keyboard will not show in graphical view

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am developing a softkeyboard I have tried several codes  in the main.xml file but none of the codes display the keyboard in graphical view

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

The soft keyboard won't show up in the graphical view because it is a custom view -- the graphical view is designed for basic android widgets only.  When you start using anything but the main Android widgets (i.e. TextView, ScrollView, Button, etc.), you're going to have to code it in XML.

The keyboard's layout and drawing methods change dynamically based on the number of keys, the keyboard theme, key icons, etc.  This happens at **runtime** and thus cannot be displayed before the app is run.